# Promtail: Expand env variable on Windows

Tags: windows, grafana-loki, promtail

I'm running Promtail on Windows, using environment variables as described here: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/configuration/#use-environment-variables-in-the-configuration
.

Here is my config.yaml:

```
client:
    external_labels:   
        instance: ${FOO}
        instance_id: ${BAR}
```

Now I set the two variables:

```
PS> $FOO="foo"
PS> $BAR="bar"
PS> echo $FOO
foo
PS> echo $BAR
bar
```

And then I start promtail with the flags `--config.expand-env=true` to use environment variable references in the configuration file and `--print-config-stderr` to get a quick output of the entire Promtail config.

However, the result is:

```
client:
  external_labels: |
    instance: ""
    instance_id: ""
```

The variables are not replaced as expected.

(I also tried the same with `$Env:FOO` and `$Env:BAR`)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try Modifying the config.yaml file to

```
client:
    external_labels:   
        instance: "${FOO}"
        instance_id: "${BAR}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).